# How to check sequence in string using regular expression

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I want to check input string is in correct format. ^[\d-.]+$ expression check only existance of numbers and .(dot) and -(minus) But I want to check its sequence also.

Suppose I want to use calculator with . and - only. How to get regular expression which satify below all conditions.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[\d-\.]+$")
   //this expression works for below conditions only
    if string v1="10-20-30";  // should return true
    if string v1="10-20";  // should return true
    if string v1="10.20";  // should return true
    if string v1="10R20";  // should return false
    if string v1="10@20";  // should return false
    if string v1="10-20.30.40-50";  // should return true
    if string v1="10";  // should return true

    //above expression not works for below conditions
    if string v1="10--20.30"; // should return false
    if string v1="10-20-30..";  // should return false
    if string v1="--10-20.30";  // should return false
    if string v1="-10-20.30";  // should return false
    if string v1="10-20.30.";  // should return false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like

```
        var pattern = @"^(\d+(-|\.))*\d+$";
```

should do the job for you.

What this regex "is saying" is:

1. Find one or more digits (\d+)
2. Followed by a minus sign or dot (-|.) - need to escape the dot here with \
3. This could be 0 or more times in the string - the star sign in the end (\d+(-|.))*
4. And then another one or more digits (\d+).
5. All this should be right after the beginning of the string and right before the end (the ^ and $ I believe you know about).

Note: If you need to be possible the numbers to be negative, you will need to add another conditional minus sign before both \d+ instances in the regex or :

var pattern = @"^(-?\d+(-|.))*-?\d+$";

Regards